# Chaining observables (that are network requests)

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I have a network request called `login` that returns an `Observable<UserInfo>`.  I need to make another API call from that result based on whether the data returned from `login` has a count > 1, otherwise, I just need to go to a different view controller.  I’m trying to use `flatMapLatest` to do the check for the first request `login` and make the next network call `jobStates` (which returns an `Observable<JobState>`, but I don’t think I’m arranging them correctly.   Any ideas?  Is there a better / easier way to do this?

Here's what it looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would expect to see something like this:

```
func login() {
    let loginResult = networkService
        .login(login: usernameTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!)
        .share()

    loginResult
        .filter { $0.count > 1 }
        .subscribe(onNext: { userInfo in
            // stop here and go to a different view with userInfo data
        })
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)

    let networkService = self.networkService // so you don't have to capture self below
    loginResult
        .filter { $0.count <= 1 }
        .flatMapLatest { networkService.jobStates(locationId: $0.locationId) }
        .subscribe(
            onNext: { data in
                // do whatever with data from second request
        },
            onError: { error in
                // if either request errors, you will end up here.

        })
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

When you have two different possible outcomes, you need two different subscribes.

Comment: That solution worked great!  I'm doing something similar in another area of my app and I'd love some advice on how to clean it up.  If you're interested in taking a look, I posted the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56623583/re-organizing-chained-observables